# JPA Hibernate cascade type for child of child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I was looking for documentation or answer how will the cascade work for child of child , example :

```
public class Parent{
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Child> child;
}

public class Child{
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="child")
      private List<AnotherChild> anohterChild;
    }
  @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
}
```

now the question, will the cascade operation applied on "Child" from parent class apply to "AnotherChild" ?
in other words if I persist "Parent" Object will it persist "AnotherChild" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you persist your parent, only those childs which are in the child-list of your parent-class get persisted but not the list of AnotherChilds in your child-class.

If you wish to persist them too just cascade it too:

```
public class Child{
     @OneToMany(mappedBy="child", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
     private List<AnotherChild> anohterChild;

     @ManyToOne
     private Parent parent;
}
```

And just use `CascadeType.ALL`when you really need it, because this cascade-type includes more than just persisting. As it is explained in the following picture, `CascadeType.ALL` includes all other cascade-types including the cascade-type "remove" which means that, when your parent-object gets removed, all other child-objects get removed too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need to wait more time to see more answers

Comment: What do you need?

Comment: Just to add: -
CascadeType.REFRESH: means children of parent will not be inserted, if parent is getting inserted, but they will be updated if parent is being updated (i.e. all entities are in persist mode)

Comment: Is there a way I can cascade only fetch operations?