# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException persisting nested children with CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a class called `Human` which has a list of dogs :

```java
@Entity
public class Human {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<>(List.of(new Dog()));

    ...
}
```

The dog class `Dog` has a list of puppies :

```java
@Entity
public class Dog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Puppy> puppies = new HashSet<>(List.of(new Puppy()));
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Puppy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

When I try to create a new human that has a dog and the dog has a puppy and I save the human using an Hibernate JPA repository with Spring :

```java
Human human = new Human();
Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<>();
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setPuppies(new HashSet<>(List.of(new Puppy())));
dogs.add(dog);
human.setDogs(dogs);
humanRepository.save(human);
```

I get the following error :

`org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Puppy`

But if I create the human, with the default values and save him with the human repository, it works and it saves the puppy.

```java
Human human = new Human();
humanRepository.save(human);
```

I don't understand why the puppy is not automatically saved and I don't want to use a separate repository to save the puppy. Shouldn't Hibernate automatically save my puppy as the Dog defines `CascadeType.ALL`? Just like they say on this stackoverflow : [JPA Hibernate cascade type for child of child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468371/jpa-hibernate-cascade-type-for-child-of-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change cascade type to persist in your association annotation

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true)

Comment: After some troubleshooting, the problem came from `CascadeType.MERGE`. I don't fully understand what is the cause, but I'm guessing it should work ok without it. Of course my new entities are detached when I instantiate them, but my guess would have been that JPA uses persist first instead of merge.

Comment: Actually I found out that my problem was not from persisting a new entity but saving an already existing one. And disabling CascadeType.MERGE cancelled the "update" on the children. I will create a separate ticket to find out about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278086/spring-data-jpa-remove-children-automatically-instead-of-throwing-object-refere