# Spring data JPA - Hibernate - TransientObjectException when updating an existing entity with transient nested children

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Following my first question here, the question has changed so I'm creating a new one : [org.hibernate.TransientObjectException persisting nested children with CascadeType.ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62176320/org-hibernate-transientobjectexception-persisting-nested-children-with-cascadety/62176939#62176939)

I found that my problem was not saving a new entity but updating an existing one.

Let's start from the beginning.

I have a class called Human which has a list of dogs :

```java
@Entity
public class Human {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<>(List.of(new Dog()));

    ...
}
```

The dog class Dog has a list of puppies :

```java
@Entity
public class Dog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Puppy> puppies = new HashSet<>(List.of(new Puppy()));
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Puppy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

I'm trying to get an existing human that has a dog and the dog has a puppy, if I try to give him a new Dog with another set of puppies :

```java
Human human = humanRepository.findById(id); // This human already had a dog and the dog has puppies
Set<Dog> dogs = new HashSet<>();
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setPuppies(new HashSet<>(List.of(new Puppy())));
dogs.add(dog);
human.setDogs(dogs);
humanRepository.save(human);
```

I get the following error :

```java
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.test.Puppy
```

In my understanding `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}` should persist the children automatically when saving them with a `CrudRepository`.

**EDIT:**

The problem comes from the creation of a new dog with puppies when I'm updating an existing entity.

Here are the working examples I tried :

```java
Human human = new Human();
Dog dog = new Dog();
Puppy puppy = new Puppy();
dog.getPuppies().clear();
dog.getPuppies().add(puppy);
human.getDogs().clear();
human.getDogs().add(dog);
humanRepository.save(human);
```

```java
Human human = humanRepository.findById(id);
human.getDogs().clear();
human.getDogs().add(new Dog());
humanRepository.save(human);
```

But the following one doesn't work whether the human I retrieve already has dogs or not :

```java
Human human = humanRepository.findById(id);
Dog dog = new Dog();
Puppy puppy = new Puppy();
dog.getPuppies().clear();
dog.getPuppies().add(puppy);
human.getDogs().clear();
human.getDogs().add(dog);
humanRepository.save(human);
```

Apparently, persisting a transient Human will cascade persist to the children and the children of the children.

Updating an existing Human will cascade persist to the children but not the children of the children and thus cause the `TransientObjectException`.

Is this expected behaviour? Am I supposed to use a separate repository to persist the dogs and puppies?

Comment: Don't do things like this `dog.setPuppies` and `human.setDogs(dogs);``. Instead add it to the already existing persisted and managed collection (and remove it as well).

Comment: So `human.getDogs().clear()` and then `human.getDogs().add(dog);`? I will try and let you know, thanks!

Comment: I still get the same error. I've tried going along and clearing the puppies in the HashSet too. `human.getDogs().forEach(e -> e.getPuppies().clear());`. I've also had to put `FetchType.EAGER` everywhere, otherwise I'd get another error with lazy initialisation and `@Transactional` doesn't help with that.

Comment: You need to set the relation to null as well. Else it isn't an orphan

Comment: Do you mean something like that `human.getDogs().forEach(dog -> dog.getPuppies().forEach(puppy -> puppy.setDog(null)))`? That wouldn't work because puppy doesn't reference dog. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: The problem is you are also creating the instance with a list always containing a single reference (dog or puppy), which is the unsaved one. Also never set the collect ion as that will destroy the managed collection. Remove the dog from the collection before creating a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure I completly understand what you are proposing, but I fiddled a bit and if I'm only calling `human.getDogs().clear();` it does work. So the problem is not the deletion of the old dog, but the creation of the new one and its children. I think that, when I create a new human with a new dog, it will cascade the `PERSIST` action. However, when I update an existing human with a new dog, it will not cascade the `PERSIST` action but `MERGE` instead. What do you think about it?

Comment: THe problem is when you are creating a dog the puppies are initialized with an collection with 1 element. You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: What should I do instead? Create the puppy and the dog with separate repositories before adding them to the human? I updated my question with new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `save` on a JPA repository will either call `persist` if the entity is transient or `merge` if the entity is detached.

If it calls persist, the persist will cascade and save all the children entities but not update existing ones.

If it calls merge, the merge operation will cascade and merge all the children that have an Id, but it will not persist the ones that don't have an Id.

The Hibernate specific `saveOrUpdate` method seems to do this job. If anyone know of any other method available through JPA, please let me know.

**EDIT**

I've actually managed to use spring repositories to save my entity. However I need to persist manually every new child and grandchild. For this I have written a method that uses the reflection API!

```java
void saveNewEntites(Object entity, EntityManager em) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clazz = entity.getClass();
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(OneToMany.class)) {
            for(Object child : (Collection<?>)field.get(entity)){
                for(Field childField : child.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
                    childField.setAccessible(true);
                    if(childField.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class) && childField.get(child) == null){
                        em.persist(child);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                saveNewEntites(child, em);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is how my update method looks:

```
@RequestMapping(method = PATCH, path = "/{id}")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "Entity updated")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Data is invalid for update")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid ResourceDTO resource) {

    ResourceEntity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);

    copyProperties(resource, entity);

    try {
        saveNewEntites(entity, em);
        repository.save(entity);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new InvalidCommandException("Data is invalid for update.");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

The `copyProperties` method also uses reflection to copy all the properties. It uses the `clear` and `addAll` method on OneToMany relations.